# Get dict's value by key name in Django Tempaltes

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in my `view.py` I have a function with field: `context ={'user':user, 'user_gpds':user_gpds, 'team':team, 'team_gpds':team_gpds}`
which I return:

```
return render(request, 'app/team_gpd_page/team_gpds.html', context)
```

in my templates I have next code:

```
{% for gpd in {{context|key:team_gpds}} %}
            <tr>
                <td><a class="nav-link" href="/gpd/{{gpd.employee.end_user_id}}">GPD</a></td>
                <td>{{gpd.employee}}</td>
                <td>{{gpd.gpd_year}}</td>
                <td>{{gpd.gpd_start}}</td>
                <td>{{gpd.gpd_end}}</td>
                <td>{{gpd.gpd_status}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

But in result I have had an empty fields. I am also trying `context.team_gpds` and `context.get('team_gpds')`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `team_gpds` queryset ?

Comment: yes,  <QuerySet [<GPD: GPD 2021 for person1>, <GPD: GPD 2021 for person2>]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `team_gpds` is `querysets` then you can loop through `querysets` as

```
{% for gpd in team_gpds %}
   <tr>
       <td><a class="nav-link" href="/gpd/{{gpd.employee.end_user_id}}">GPD</a></td>
       <td>{{gpd.employee}}</td>
       <td>{{gpd.gpd_year}}</td>
       <td>{{gpd.gpd_start}}</td>
       <td>{{gpd.gpd_end}}</td>
       <td>{{gpd.gpd_status}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```